# Matlab efficiency: small for-loop

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I wrote some Matlab code that works so far, but is very slow when running with a big matrix. I identified the bottleneck of my code as a for-loop.

What the code is supposed to do is look at one column (ic) of the H-matrix, compare with other columns that have at least one 1-entry in common with ic and add their ones to the ic vector. This happens until there are no more changes in the ic vector.

Here is a small example:

H = ( 1 0 1 ; 1 1 0 ; 0 0 1 ) and ic = ( 1 1 0 )^T (the first column of H). The code then takes for example the first 1 of ic, compares in its row if another column also has a 1 as its first entry, finds the third column ( 1 0 1 )^T and then adds all of the ones to the ic vector that are in the found column, in this case the third entry, so that ic = ( 1 1 1 )^T.

At first I used two for-loops:

*H* is a (500 x 1000) sparse matrix (but is supposed to be (5000 x 10 000) when the code runs faster).

*ic* is a (500 x 1) vector.

*i* is the index of the ic vector the code starts with.

Code 1 (old version):

```
for c = find(ic).'
     for v = find(H(c,:))
          if v ~= i
              ic = ic | H(:,v);
          end
     end
end
```

Then I tried to improve my code and make it faster with vectorization:

Code 2 (new version):

```
for c = find(ic).'
     ic( sum(H(:,find(H(c,:))'),2) > 0 ) = 1;
end
```

The second line of code 2 is called 1769302 times and takes up 97.4% of the time which is 30.568s. It is called that many times because the ic vector has to be determined while constructing the H-matrix and is called almost before any 1 added in the H-matrix.
The time already improved compared to code 1, where the second line took 20.209s and the 4th line took 31.950s. My goal is running my code with a (5000 x 10 000) H-matrix and it not taking longer than 3min.

The H-matrix is built during the runtime of the code. Before almost every 1 that is added to the matrix, the function with the mentioned code in it is called. The ic vector is then updated in a while-loop, until it no longer changes or there are no more zeros in the ic vector. The while-loop looks like this:

Code 3 (context):

```
ic2 = ic;

while true

     for c = find(ic).'
          ic( sum(H(:,find(H(c,:))'),2) > 0 ) = 1;
     end
     
     if isequal(ic0,ic)
          return;
     end
     ic0 = ic;

     if sum(ic(:,1)) == size(H,1)
          return;
     else
          ic2 = ic;
     end

end
```

The only purpose of *ic0* is comparing *ic* between iterations.

*ic2* saves the state of *ic* before it only consists of ones.

I would very much appreciate any answer that could help me further improve the runtime of my code and I apologize for not being very experienced in Matlab programming. Thank you very much for any answer!

Comment: If `H` is very large (and 5,000x10,000 is), then the transpose operation `'` (or `.'`) will be very costly. Without knowing more details I can't help with the specifics. Also worth looking into is using `parfor` loops if you have the Parallel computing toolbox. Sometimes it's possible to get rid of a `find` command by using logical indexing - have a look at the rest of your code and see if you can implement that.

Comment: What is  `i` in  `if v ~= i` ?

Comment: It would help if you could explain what the desired ouput is (it's hard to follow from the loop-based code). Maybe give a small example with input and desired output

Comment: How is the second line of code called 1,769,302 times, when the loop runs over the non zero elements of `ic` which is a [500x1] vector ?? Surely there can't be more than 500 non-zero elements in `ic`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, I edited my question and hopefully clarified it.

Comment: As in other comments stated you shoud provide a minimal reproducible example. The two versions of code that you have provided appear that be different. Where you have used `i` in the second code?

Comment: I added a small example:

Comment: H = ( 1 0 1 ; 1 1 0 ; 0 0 1 ) and ic = ( 1 1 0 )^T (the first column of H). The code then takes for example the first 1 of ic, compares in its row if another column also has a 1 as its first entry, finds the third column ( 1 0 1 )^T and then adds all of the ones to the ic vector that are in the found column, in this case the third entry, so that ic = ( 1 1 1 )^T.

Comment: Can't `i` be replaced by `c` ? And please edit your question and add the example in text of the question.

Comment: `c` refers to the rows of the matrix while `v` refers to the columns. `i` is the index of the position of the `ic` vector (column) in the `H` matrix. I had already added the example to the question when I wrote in the comments that I had edited it, but added the example in the comments, too, because you asked again. Thank you anyways for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends if you want to check the whole ic vector again, after adding a one to it. Because if you add a one at a point in the vector, that you already processed, you might have some new connections to the other columns. However if you dont want to check again, after adding ones to the ic vector, you can use the following:

```
H = [ 1 0 1 ; 
      1 1 0 ; 
      0 0 1 ];
  
ic = [1; 
      1; 
      0];

Htemp = H+ic;

ic = any(H(:, any(Htemp>1)),2);
```

To check until ic doesnt change anymore, you could try the following:

```
ic = H(:,1);
a = true;
s = 0;
ic2 = ic;
while a
    Htemp   = H+ic;
    ic      = any(H(:, any(Htemp>1)),2);
    Htemp   = H+ic;
    if s == sum(ic)
        a = false;
    else
        s = sum(ic);
        a = true;
    end
    if sum(ic(:,1)) == size(H,1)
        return;
    else
        ic2 = ic;
    end
end
```

For my random matrix this doesnt take more than two iterations through the while loop, but it should do exactly what your code above does, only quicker. It took roughly 0.9 seconds to compute.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works and is about 26% faster. Unfortunately my code still takes very long when I run it with a large matrix. I would be very thankful for further suggestions to improve the efficiency of my code.

Comment: Thats interesting, I just tried it with the matrix size you gave, and it takes around 0.5 seconds to compute...

Comment: The problem is that I construct the H matrix during the runtime of my code and before almost every 1 I add in the matrix, I need to determine ic. Consequently, for the (500 x 1000) matrix the lines are called 11574 times which takes about 12s. My goal would be running the code with a (5000 x 10 000) matrix.

Comment: I still dont get how you archieve 11574 calls for a 500x1000 matrix. Maybe share a bit more of your code if possible or tell us how you build your matrix, this might help to understand your problem.

Comment: I edited my question and hope that helps understanding my problem. Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: But you still iterate through ic, you dont actually need that with my code. Before you enter the while loop, H is fully built right? My code in the second code field above replaces the whole while loop and takes only half a secon to compute for a Matrix of your size

Comment: H doesn´t change in the while loop. If I try your second code without the while loop, not all of the ones are marked in ic and I get a different result. The code should check for connections to other columns after every one that is added to ic until there are no more changes in ic.

Comment: I added a third solution, maybe this does the trick?

Comment: I just noticed, that I did an error in the for loop of the second solution, but my while loop should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now apart from a little mistake I made. I forgot to mention I need a vector (I called it ic2 and added it to code 3 in my question) that saves the state of ic before it only consists of ones. I can`t figure out where to put it in your last solution.

Comment: Alright, I did another edit on my answer, now it should fit your purpose completely :D

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately, using your last answer, running my code the function takes in total almost 29s while your first answer in my original while loop takes almost 22s when I use a (500 x 1000) matrix. The while loops are called 2000 times and the ic updating is done about 12000 times. Although this is faster than my first try, it unfortunately is still too slow for the (5000 x 10000) matrix.

Comment: That is interesting: logically,  for a 500x1000 you can only change ic 500 times, before every possible 0 is replaced by a 1, therefore the maximum amount of calls should be 500 in the absolute worst case... What do you mean by "the while loop is called 2000 times and theic updating 12000"? Shouldnt that be exactly the same, as in every iteration of the while loop, ic is changed once?

Comment: I am sorry, I should have expressed myself better. The function with the while loop is called 2000 times, every time before another 1 is added to the H matrix. If you add all the iterations of the while loop in the 2000 function calls, ic is updated 12000 times. ic is not always the same vector when the function is called. It is a different column of the H matrix every second time the function is called.